# How do I print out my object array in React Native Expo?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

How do I print out the values I see in my console? I need to display them in the app I am running in React Native using Expo. Do I need to map through the object array and print out values, or run the MyProfile a different way because it is asynced?

Thanks!

```
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/core";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import { auth } from "../firebase";
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import { Animate } from "react-native-entrance-animation";
import Copyright from "./Copyright";

const ProfileScreen = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const MyProfile = () => {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState(null);
    let myPosts = "Profile loading...";

    const collectIdsAndDocs = (doc) => {
      return { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() };
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      const getPost = async () => {
        const snapshot = await firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection("profiles")
          .where("email", "==", auth.currentUser.email)
          .get();
        myPosts = snapshot.docs.map(collectIdsAndDocs);
        console.log(myPosts);
        setPosts({ myPosts });
      };
      getPost();
    }, []);
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{/*how do I print out values here!? I see them in console*/}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already calls the `setPosts` `useState` hook, you can access `posts` in your rendering code:

```
return (
  <View>
     {posts.map((post) => (
       <Text>{post.id}</Text>
     ))}
  </View>
);
```

---

To solve the `null` problem, pass in an empty array as the initial value when you define the state:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
```

Comment: I'm getting `null is not an object (evaluating 'posts.map')`

Comment: And then I'm getting `undefined is not a function (near '...posts.map...')` if I check if posts is null and return appropriately

Comment: See the update in my answer, but please also [search for your error messages](https://www.google.com/search?q=reactjs+null+is+not+an+object+(evaluating+%27posts.map%27)) going forward - as this one has been covered before.

Comment: I actually had a very dumb error and changed my setPosts({myPosts}) to setPosts(myPosts) and that fixed the rest, thanks for the map!